# Upgrading OpenGL Drivers

Tags: fedora, drivers, gpu, opengl

I'm trying to learn OpenGL and most tutorials on the internet only offer
guidelines for OpenGL 3.0 and higher. So I looked for my OpenGL version and

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

yields this:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.0.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
```

So I went to the offical site for these drivers:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/

I installed the latest version but it still says the same. I know my hardware is capable of doing some DirectX11 rendering so why wouldn't it support OpenGL3.0?

Oh, I forgot: I'm using Fedora 20 64bit

Comment: I'm getting `OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.5` on HD 4000 and mesa-dri-drivers-10.1.5-1.20140607.fc20.x86_64.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that the Ironlake graphics architecture is not ivy bridge or sandy bridge
It's Clarkdale/Arrendale gen technology which, while the hardware strictly speaking supports the extensions, does not have these features implemented in the relevant graphics drivers.

You could take a stab at adding them yourself if you have experience with driver programming.

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMxMDQ

The relevant section, in case the link goes down:

> "While Ironlake (Clarkdale/Arrandale) -- the generation of Intel
>   hardware prior to Sandy Bridge -- was designed during the OpenGL 2.1
>   days, much of the OpenGL 3.0 / GL Shading Language 1.30 functionality
>   can be implemented for this hardware. As Intel Linux customers were
>   quick to discuss when sharing this morning there's now OpenGL ES 3.0
>   for Sandy Bridge (the embedded/mobile GL variant), driver developers
>   quickly lose interest in older hardware.
>
> One Phoronix reader pointed out this bug report with commentary by
>   Kenneth Graunke from January:
>
> Team Fortress 2 requires some functionality from OpenGL 3.0 and GLSL 1.30, which we currently only support on Sandy Bridge and newer
>   hardware. Unfortunately, Ironlake and earlier currently do not.
>
> It should be possible to implement the missing functionality on Ironlake. The code is open source, and the hardware documentation is
>   freely available on the web(*), so in theory, anyone could make
>   progress toward this.
>
> Sadly, our team is extremely busy working on newer hardware and is unlikely to have time to implement GL 3.0 support for Ironlake...at
>   least not any time soon. I sincerely apologize for this; we'd all love
>   to see it happen too.
>
> ```
> (*) https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/driver-documentation-prms
> ```
>
> Basically, Intel Linux driver developers are busy working on newer
>   hardware and other features, so missing functionality for older Intel
>   products likely won't come. But since Intel does provide NDA-free
>   programming documentation, other capable developers should be able to
>   provide the said features. This bug comment was in response to
>   Ironlake not working for Valve's Source Engine games on Linux.
>
> While I do own some Ironlake hardware, I would much rather see Intel
>   working on the newer hardware support. Even if the Intel i965 DRI
>   driver implemented the necessary GL3/GLSL1.30 features for the Source
>   Engine games, it would still be damn slow. It wasn't until Sandy
>   Bridge that Intel graphics really got their act together in terms of
>   integrated graphics performance. Ironlake isn't too capable and the
>   newer (and yet-to-be-released) hardware is much more exciting and will
>   open new doors. Intel also, obviously, wants you to upgrade your
>   hardware too."

So the simple answer is: Intel doesn't care enough or have any incentive to implement the features, but at least you /could/ implement them if you wanted and had the skillset/funding to do so.
I would recommend upgrading your hardware if you need OGL 3.x features as they are not and most likely will not be supported under the Ironlake architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then compiling these directly from source I'd be inclined to download the source RPMs, modify the configuration switch within the RPM `.spec` file and rebuild them. This would appear to be the only thing missing from the Fedora packages, see here: [Why Fedora do not ship OpenGL 3.0? (even disable it for Intel HW)](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/8311/why-fedora-do-not-ship-opengl-30-even-disable-it-for-intel-hw/).

*excerpt from: [[Mesa-users] Advertised OpenGL version on IvyBridge](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-users/2013-February/000561.html)*

> On Sun, 2013-02-17 at 00:48 -0600, Michael Cronenworth wrote:
>
> > I heard on Phoronix that IvyBridge/SandyBridge hardware is supposed to 
> >     have OpenGL 3.0/3.1 support on Mesa 9.0 and 9.1. However, glxinfo is 
> >     telling me something different.
> >
> > CPU: Core i3-3225 (HD4000)
> >     Distro: Fedora 18 x86_64
> >     OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
> >     OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop
> >     OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.0.1
> >     OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
> >
> > Is this accurate or is Phoronix mistaken?
>
> HD4000 does indeed support OpenGL 3.1.  However because of US patent
>   implications Fedora builds Mesa without --enable-texture-float
>   configure option and this disables OpenGL 3.0/3.1.  I'm not a lawyer
>   but AFAIK since it is not world-wide patent it is safe to use
>   --enable-texture-float if you are outside US, and some Linux distros like Ubuntu do so by default.  Rebuilding Mesa from source RPM on
>   Fedora 18 with the named option enables OpenGL 3.1/shading 1.40 on my
>   HD3000.
>
> --    Tomash Brechko

#### Steps

Here are roughly the steps:

```
$ yumdownloader --source mesa-libGL
$ rpmdev-setuptree
$ rpm -Uvh mesa-9.2.4-1.20131128.fc19.src.rpm
$ (umask 022; sudo yum-builddep mesa-9.2.4-1.20131128.fc19.src.rpm)
$ (umask 022; sudo yum install gcc-c++)
```

Then edit the `mesa.spec` file:

```
$ vim ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/mesa.spec
```

Then add the switch to the `.spec` file:

```
## add the --enable-texture-float to configure
```

Now rebuild the package using the `.spec` file:

```
$ rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/mesa.spec
```

You should now see newly built `.rpm` files in your RPMS directory when all is complete.

#### References

- [Introduction to MesaLib - Chapter 24. X Window System Environment - Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/mesalib.html)

Comment: Ok - I did everything as you said and installed every .rpm file in the RPMS/x86_64 directory. But it still says OpenGL 2.1 . But I noticed something: in the mesa.spec file was --enable-texture-float already set...

Comment: @haansn08 - I noticed this as well when I went through it too.